# Should a scheduled task remain in the "Running" state?

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch, windows-task-scheduler

I'm new to using the task scheduler and I'm using it to run a batch file provided online when the computer boots. I r-clicked it and told it to run. It did and all is fine, but the Status of the task is still "Running." I just want to make sure that's okay. Or since it's already done its job, should it end in some way?

The batch file mounts a network drive such that it can be used at the system level.

```
net use x: \\tplinklogin.net\volume2 /persistent:yes
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Task Scheduler window doesn't automatically refresh, which could lead you to believe it's still running. Clicking the Refresh link on the right side panel should hopefully show it change.

Comment: F5 also refreshes it.  Very short sighted of Microsoft to not automatically refresh it.

Comment: Refresh did not work for me. Still showing "Running". I have another task, that shows "Ready" (after it ran once).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - the task worked but the status kept showing Running.  One simple thing to try is click on the Task Scheduler Library in the left column.  Click Action/Refresh.  Presto.  Status changed to Ready.  That's all it was for me, the task ran fine, just the status didn't update.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Im having this issue.  The task succeed, but the status remains "Running" no matter if i refresh or not.

Comment: On digging in a bit again, I found the issue.  I was pointing to a script in a different folder than I thought.  The actual script being used had a line of code using Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit" which will put the script in interactive mode.